# How to access file from other domain from stackoverflow or JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I want to create sample demo in JsFiddle or on Stackoverflow. And the demo requires to download a pdf using `pdf.js`. But both web sites are giving CORS error.

I would like to know are there any domains that are allowed from `JSFiddle` or `Stackoverflow`?

Comment: sorry may be i asked the question wrong. so is there public domain where i can post sample files or domain which already has sample files that i can use for testing and has CORS enable?

Comment: I misinterpreted it then. But I'm afraid that asking to find/recommend off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow.